# Add number to array by split and show them in desecnding order after taking input in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, split

this is my code. i need to take input from user into an array using split so that i can take multiple number in one form. Then sort them and show in ascending order. plz help

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <script>
    var notesArray = Array();

    function array() {
      let splits = document.getElementById("text1").value.split('~');

      for (var i = 0; i < splits.length; i++) {
        notesArray.push(splits[i]);
      }
  
      document.getElementById("text1").value = "";
    }

    function display_array() {
      var e = "<hr/>";

      for (var y = 0; y < notesArray.length; y++) {
        e += "Element " + y + " = " + notesArray[y] + "<br/>";
      }
  
      document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML = e;
    }
  </script>
        
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="text1"></input><br>
    <input type="button" id="button1" value="Add" onclick="array();"></input><br>
    <input type="button" id="button2" value="Display" onclick="display_array();"></input><br>
    <div id="Result"></div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

my function may not work here. what is the best way to do the sorting?

Comment: `<input>` elements are self-closing (`<input />`) and don't have an explicit closing tag (`</input>`).

Comment: _"my function **may** not work here"_ - What's the actual problem here? -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask); _"what is the best way to do the sorting?"_ - You will find plenty of resources on that topic here on SO -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: i need to sort integer from user input.